# Grunt usemin, get final path of compressed files to allow preload

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, preload, grunt-usemin

I have a HTML block like this for minify css and js files:

```
<!-- build:css static/assets/css/combined.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/bower_components/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/bower_components/photoswipe/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/assets/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/assets/css/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/assets/css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/common/da-angular-spinkit/angular-spinkit.min.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I need to make a preload of the resource `static/assets/css/combined.css` but  the final file has a hash at the end of its name, so the final path is like `static/assets/css/combined.min-af5890ce41.css`, so I don't know how to include the following tag:

```
<link rel="preload" href="static/assets/css/combined.min-af5890ce41.css"/>
 -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Because I don't know what is the final name of the generated minified file.

How can I get the output of this generated file? I only need the final path name. I search about `grunt-usemin` but seems to be "minimalist".

Thank you.

### EDIT

I found on the project some pieces of grunt code if you can see what module is acting on the file hashes:

`/client/static/bower_components/bootstrap/Gruntfile.js`:

Here I can see:

- jshint
- uglify
- less
- csslint
- cssmin
- csscomb
- htmlmin

I can't see what of this modules acts on the `build:js` or `build:css` in the index.html.

`/client/static/bower_components/photoswipe/Gruntfile.js`:

Here I can see npm tasks:

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jekyll');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-aws-s3');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svgmin');
```

### EDIT 2

On the folder `/dev/` there is a gruntfile.js with this code (it seems not related):

```
var src = "../src/client/";

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-angular-gettext");

    // We extract translations with 'grunt nggettext_extract'. Those files go to '/dev/translations-extract' directory.
    grunt.initConfig({
        nggettext_extract: {
            pot: {
                files: {
                    'translations-extract/template.pot': [src + 'static/common/**/*.html', src + 'static/states/**/*.html', src + 'index.html', src + 'indexMobile.html']
                }
            },
        },
        // We compile those files (*.po) with 'grunt nggettext_compile. The translations.js file goes to /client/static/util/translations/ dir.
        nggettext_compile: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    module: 'alvarez',
                },
                files: {
                    '../src/client/static/common/translations/translations.js': ['translations-extract/*.po']
                }
            },
        },
    })
}
```

And then, on `/dev/bower_components/`  there are tons of plugins, each one with its gruntfile.js inside.

### EDIT 3

Found on `/ops/` a **gulpfile.js** and seems to be related

```
/**
 * Crea una versión de distribución concatenada y minificada
 */

var gulp = require('gulp');
var run = require('gulp-run');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var del = require('del');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
var embedTemplates = require('./embed-templates/index.js');
var dist = './dist/';
var indexDist = dist + 'client/';
var HTMLDist = indexDist + 'static/';
var src = '../src/';
var assetsSrc = src + 'client/static/assets/'
var cssSrc = assetsSrc + 'css/';
var serverDist = dist + 'server/';
var libDist = dist + 'lib/';

// pm2
// Init-dist
gulp.task('pm2', function () {
    run('pm2 start ' + serverDist + 'alvarez.js').exec();
});

// Init-stop
gulp.task('pm2-stop', function () {
    run('pm2 stop ' + serverDist + 'alvarez.js').exec();
});

//Init-restart
gulp.task('pm2-restart', function () {
    run('pm2 restart ' + serverDist + 'alvarez.js').exec();
});

// npm-install on dist
gulp.task('npm-install-dist', function () {
    run('npm install --production --prefix ' + serverDist).exec();
})

// Dist subtasks

// Cleaning dist
gulp.task('del-dist', function () {
    del(dist, {
        force: true
    }, console.log('Files deleted'));
});

// Moving index.js
gulp.task('move-server-js', function () {
    return gulp.src([src + 'server/alvarez.js', src + 'server/package.json'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(serverDist));
});

gulp.task('move-config-js', function () {
    return gulp.src([src + 'server/lib/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(serverDist + 'lib/'))
})

//gulp.task('move-lib-js', function () {
//    return gulp.src(src + 'lib/config.js')
//        .pipe(gulp.dest(libDist));
//});
//
//gulp.task('move-boot-pro', function () {
//    return gulp.src(src + 'lib/boot.pro.js')
//        .pipe(rename('boot.js'))
//        .pipe(gulp.dest(libDist));
//})

// Moving html
gulp.task('move-html', function () {
    var opts = {
        empty: true
    };
    return gulp.src([src + 'client/static/**/**/*.html', src + 'client/static/**/**/*.swf'])
        .pipe(minifyHTML(opts))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(HTMLDist));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', ['move-assets', 'move-html-index', 'move-html-index-mobile'], function() {
    return gulp.src(HTMLDist + 'assets/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(HTMLDist + 'assets/css/'));
})

gulp.task('move-assets', function () {
    return gulp.src(src + '/client/static/assets/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(HTMLDist + 'assets/'));
});

// Moving html index
gulp.task('move-html-index', function () {
    var assets = useref.assets();
    //.pipe(gulpif('**\/da-*.js', embedTemplates()))
    return gulp.src(src + 'client/index.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', embedTemplates()))
        .pipe(gulpif('.*\.js', ngAnnotate()))
        .pipe(gulpif('.*\.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(indexDist));
});

gulp.task('move-html-index-mobile', function () {
    var assets = useref.assets();
    return gulp.src(src + 'client/indexMobile.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', embedTemplates()))
        .pipe(gulpif('.*\.js', ngAnnotate()))
        .pipe(gulpif('.*\.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(indexDist));
})

gulp.task('embed-templates', [], function () {
    return gulp.src([src + 'client/static/states/**/da*/*.js', src + 'client/static/common/**/da*/*.js'])
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', embedTemplates()))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(indexDist))
});

// Build dist task
gulp.task('build-dist', ['move-html', 'move-server-js', 'move-config-js', 'minify-css'], function () {
    console.log('Dist ready...');
});
```

Comment: Please post the content of the `Gruntfile.js`

Comment: @muecas Done, code updated, tell me if you need more.

Comment: No, that `Gruntfile.js` is not related to the issue. Maybe you can check all the `Gruntfile.js` files in your project. Or just post the content of this one `/client/static/bower_components/photoswipe/Gruntfile.js`. Maybe you have some other `Gruntfile.js` controlling the issue.

Comment: Yes, my main problem is that I can't found the correct gruntfile. I'm passed two days with the search, it's because I decide to ask on stackoverflow, LOL. I will make an effort to find out the correct gruntfile.

Comment: Haha, that will be great. Find all the `Gruntfile.js` in the entire project. You will need to check all the files.

Comment: I found a gulpfile.js instead, and seems to be related. Is possible that this task were performed by gulp instead grunt?

Comment: Of course! Post it!

Comment: I found `var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');` maybe it's the right place finally. I assume that I need to remove this `rev` to have the filenames without hashes, huh?

Comment: Yes, you could remove the `.pipe(rev())` and `.pipe(revReplace())` to remove the revision replace. But that will affect file cache.

Comment: I will "invent" something different for the cache. Maybe a mix from server and client, and not only on filenames. The task of preload is more important than the javascript caching, because we control the cache with server-side and expires tags are fine configured. However, thank you for put me on the correct way. I lost the time searching for grunt, when I need gulp!! I'm noob on angular/grunt/node, so need more time to learn. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @muecas well, I found it, it works, and now I can do the task if gulp lets me ahhahaha. I need to inject a preload, but the task of found the correct file (2 days lost) is done! Thank you. PD: Maybe I will update this question or maybe I open a new one.

Comment: Ok, let me know! The remaining task is to resplace the file in the preload?

Comment: Yes, I will try when the gulp injects the `<script src="combined.js">` tag , I can inject before `<link rel="preload" href="combined.js">` tag with the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no in `grunt-usemin`, but in one of the dependencies: `grunt-filerev`. This last module is the one used to create the file revisions of you `css`, `js` and other files.

After `grunt-filerev` is executed (executed as a subtask of `grunt-usemin`), it creates a summary (stored in within your grunt task, under `grunt.filerev.summary`). The summary contains the following information:

```
{
   “original.js” : “destination.59bcc35a.js”
}
```

So you could use it later on you string replacement method/module of your choice.

You can find more information about `grunt-filerev` [here](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, seems logical, but i'm new on the project and the people that makes the development is not more available to ask. I didn't find anything about `filerev`, `grunt-hash`, or `grunt-file-hash` on all the project's code. Where can I find the file `grunt.filerev.summary` in case of it exists?

Comment: _Assuming_ hashed filename can be obtained this way, updating `grunt-usemin`'s block comment (i.e.`<!-- build:css static/assets/css/combined.css -->`) to one which reflects the new hashed filename remains an issue. For that, you could  utilize a regex (e.g. [this one](https://regex101.com/r/pG76Fx/1)) with [grunt-text-replace](https://github.com/yoniholmes/grunt-text-replace), and configure `from` and `to` in task like this: `replacements: [{ from: /(<!-- build:css static\/assets\/css\/)(.*?) -->/g, to: '$1' + hashedFileName + ' -->' }]`- where `hashedFileName` is the retrieved reference.

Comment: It is not a file itself. When you run the `grunt` task, the data is stored temporarily in the grunt task itself. So you should use another task to replace the hashed version of your file name, in some other file you can use. Where does the link to the preloaded `css` is written?

Comment: I need `<link rel="preload">` on index.html, the first loaded file (to preload fonts, css and js). There is the angular include, the css include, and the grunt minifycation on the comments that I've explained on the main post. I think the result on the grunt task summary is useful if I can access to that from the html, but I think that will be impossible / hard to achieve.

Comment: You could use a technique like the one explained by @RobC; let me get you a working example of how to achieve that.

Comment: @RobC sounds very very fine. If I am not confused, I need to install that npm package, and then replace the comment with the `replacements` key. But how can I retrieve on the HTML file the result of the `to` sentence?

Comment: @muecas ok, thank you so much. I upvoted this answer because you're right about `usemin` and `filerev`

Comment: Marcos, emphasis on _"Assuming"_ was intentional in my previous comment, to my understanding it can't be retrieved (caveat: I don't used `grunt-usemin`, nor `filerev`). Tip: generate random hash(s) yourself in your build by doing something like [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758879/grunt-how-to-update-html-files-references-within-js-files-using-grunt-cache-bu/41767973#41767973)).Once you have references of hash(s) created it provides you greater control elsewhere in build. If you add pertinent parts of your Gruntfile.js to your OP, I'll see if I can access refs to hash.