# How can I rename files with Grunt in different folders and sub folders and with a version number dynamically?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, file-rename

I have a the following structure:

```
    src/
..
..

    target/
        projecta/
            css/
                vendor/
                    bootstrap.css
                               ..
                              ..

                d3.min.css
                nv.d3.min.css
                ..
                ..

            js/
                app/
                   js/
                      controllers/
                                  test.js
                               ..
                              ..

                      services/
                               application-service.js
                               ..
                              ..
                    main.js
```

I'd like to run a grunt task to rename all the files inside the target/ folder and sub folders which has js, css and html files.

I tried using the grunt-cache-bust but only first level one of the folder is updating but i need to update aggressively all the sub folders inside target/

EDIT

- Desired file name post append - bootstrap-1.0.0.css
- We want to update all the files to be updated as per above desired file name format and NOT folders
- Version number can be picked up from package.json
- We need the reference to be updated on the app for the newly added filename
  formats

Comment: check the link might be help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758879/grunt-how-to-update-html-files-references-within-js-files-using-grunt-cache-bu

Answer (score 0):

I expect what you really want here is to copy your build files into a `dist` folder and rename along the way. [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) will do this and the `process` option can rename your files for you programmatically.

You can get the version number from `package.json` using [read-pkg](https://github.com/sindresorhus/read-pkg)

So you should be able to stitch these two parts together to achieve roughly what your after.

Comment: But this does not address point four in the edit section of the OP, i.e. _"We need the reference to be updated on the app for the newly added filename formats"_

Comment: You can do this within the `process` option, as it takes a function. So you can put what ever code you like there to handle new file types.

Comment: My understanding of _"We need the reference to be updated ..."_ is e.g. **1)** A `.js` is referenced in a `.html` file using `<script src="js/main.js"></script>`. When the filename changes to `main-1.0.0.js` the script tag will need to be changed to `<script src="js/main-1.0.0.js"></script>`. **2)** Similarly for css, lets say a file is referenced using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />` - this will need to be change to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-1.0.0.css" />`. Perhaps @GOK should clarify that requirement further.

Comment: The usage of `read-pkg` is unnecessary because grunt has a builtin feature to read _package.json_. Typically something like this; `pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),` is utilized and the version is referenced using [template strings](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) e.g. `<%= pkg.version %>`. An example is shown [here](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started#an-example-gruntfile).

Answer (score 0):

1. make new js file where you can  [walk-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk-sync) pacakge to get all
   paths your recursive Dir structure
2. by using [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) package, you can get file path resolve which you get from
   walk-sync

```
const filePath=path.resolve( walk sync file path which you already get )
```

3. by using [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs), you can rename the file path

```
fs.renameSync(new_file_path, filePath)
```

then run this js file from grunt

Comment: Grunt has built-in features such as [globbing-patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) - so using additional packages such as  `walk-sync` and `path` to obtain filepaths seems really unnecessary. Also grunt includes a built-in feature to [build the files object dynamically](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) and this provides a `rename`  function so using the node.js `fs.renameSync()` method seems odd too.